# Explanation of python's while

Tags: python, while-loop

```
i = 1
while i < 5:
 print(i)
 i=+1
```

I know what `i+= 0` does, but what does it actually mean when I use `i+= 2`? It prints only 1 and 3. I have always had a problem to understand the while loop. Could you please explain to me the difference?

Comment: `i += 2` means "add 2 to i".  1 + 2 = 3, 3 + 2 = 5, etc.  Your `while` loop stops printing as soon as `i` reaches 5.

Comment: Your code is using neither `i+=0` nor `i+=2`. It is in fact an infinite loop due to a typo (`i=+1` means the same thing as `i = 1`, so `i` is *always* `1`; presumably it should be `i += 1`). Your question doesn't seem to relate to the code posted.

Answer (score 1):

`i += 2` adds two to `i`, it's equivalent to `i = i + 2`. Since `i` starts with value 1, it is printed on line 3, then `i` is incremented by 2 in the next line, making `i == 3`. In the next iteration, 3 is printed and incremented once again by 2. Since `i` is now 5, it causes the condition to fail, ending the loop.

Answer (score 0):

So, your loop is saying while `i` is smaller than 5 do:

```
print(i) # shows 1
```

Then add 2 to i, which is now 3.

```
print(i) #shows 3
```

Then add 2.
Now `i` = 5, which is not `< 5`, so the while loop ends.

Comment: So basically i is a variable and it's 1.
If I wanted to start the loop from 0 I would set the variable i with a value of 0.
When i is smaller than 9 for example and I print it out + I set the i as i+=2 then it will print 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 and not 10, because the highest number is 9, which is not printed out, cause I said n+2.

On the other hand if I chose i+=3 then it would look like 0, 3, 6, cause it's < 9 and that's why 9 must not be printed.

Comment: It's 2022, so it can safely be assumed that Python 3 is used. `print i` should be `print(i)`

Answer (score 0):

There's a diffence between: `i =+1` and `i += 1`

`i += 1` : i = i + 1(eg: if i=5 then it will be 6)

`i =+ 1` : i =  1(infinite loop because i will always be 1 so the while loop will always be true)

Ok, If `i += 1` means : `i = i + 1`(you are adding +1 to the value of i) you can easily assume that `i += 2` means adding 2 to the value of i.

So, if i = 5, if i write `i += 2` am adding 2 to 5 which is the value of i, so now i = 7.